# make a string[] to a regular string

Tags: c#

I'm trying make the user select a path, which the program will later on use, the reason why I want it to write it to a file, may be a little irrelevant but I see it as the simplest way for myself to handle the user wanting it to change it at anytime trough the GUI. I'm trying to what I believe is a string array converted to a normal string to use for File.Writealltext but I am failing to do so.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
string[] selecteddir = Directory.GetDirectories(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath).ToString();
File.WriteAllText(@"/Data/storagedir.cfg", insertstringhere);
```

The entire strech of code(form load) is as follows.

```
private void savelocation_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();

    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string[] selecteddir = Directory.GetDirectories(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath).ToString();
        File.WriteAllText(@"/Data/storagedir.cfg", insertstringhere);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong");
    }
}
```

The error is as follows:

> CS0029 "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]' "

Comment: How do you want to display each string element in your file? All on one line with no spaces between each element? Each element on a new line? Each element separated by tabs on one line? Edit: If you want each string on its own line then use [`File.WriteAllLines(string filename, string[] outputLines)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Why are you calling `ToString()` here? `Directory.GetDirectories(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath).ToString()`? What was your intent?

Comment: @Darren I didn't know you had to read all of the .NET documentation to understand any of it. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Darren I was trying to help. If the OP wants to actually hold down a job he can't very well expect to get things done in a timely manner if every time his code doesn't compile or a function doesn't behave as he expects he goes straight to SO rather than using google. Tough love was some of the best advice I got as a student. I'd advise against coddling users with this sort of behavior as you may have the misfortune of having to work along side them some day.

Comment: You weren't trying to help. You were being quick to throw one of the standard retorts around that you have seen in SO. Tough love is all fine and dandy, as long as you're at least leading someone somewhere - perhaps with a link to the page in the MASSIVE manual. Telling someone who has provided code to read the f'kin manual isn't really tough love. What would be the point of this site if we all told each other to read the f'kin manual?

Comment: whoa whoa buddy, enough with the F-bombs. My RTFM means "read the furnished materials". Googling the functions he's using on the line with the compiler error ought to be a great start. I'll concede that perhaps my comment wasn't clear enough on that.

Comment: Fair enough - there are a couple of versions of that abbreviation (https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=rtfm) (haven't come across "furnished materials" before.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To write all the directories names into `storagedir.cfg` you can use [`WriteAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string[] selecteddir = Directory.GetDirectories(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
File.WriteAllLines(@"/Data/storagedir.cfg", selecteddir);
             ^^^^^
```

That takes an array as second parameter.

Or use [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string[] selecteddir = Directory.GetDirectories(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
File.WriteAllText(@"/Data/storagedir.cfg", String.Join(", ", selecteddir);
```

---

If you're trying to save the selected path to `storagedir.cfg`:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"/Data/storagedir.cfg", olderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. i used the last: 
File.WriteAllText(@"/Data/storagedir.cfg", olderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)

Answer (score 0):

Little difficult to make out exactly what you're trying to achieve, though your problem is that you are getting a list of sub-directories with `Directory.GetDirectories(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)` but then calling `.ToString()` on it. This is throwing your error.

perhaps you don't need to store an array of directories, but only the directory that the user selected. If that is the case then you can omit that line altogether and then store the selected directory in your config.

So this:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"/Data/storagedir.cfg", insertstringhere);
```

Becomes this:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"/Data/storagedir.cfg", folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
```

Then later, when you need a list of your config directories you can read that setting from your config and get an array of directories like:

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(theStringInMyConfig);
```

Answer (score -1):

That is the corrections:

```
        string selecteddir = Directory.GetDirectories(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath).ToString();
        File.WriteAllText(selecteddir + @"\Data\storagedir.cfg", insertstringhere);
```

1. ToString() din't return aray of strings, just simple one string.
2. Use full path or ./ in path. Thats shy "selecteddir" you need, right?
3. With "@" attribute you can use a normal "\"
4. Ensure, thats a "Data" folder is exist. And what are you will doing, when the user select "Data" folder in dialog? Save into "...\Data" + @"\Data\storagedir.cfg" :) Affraid it will be too many "Data" folders inside "Data" folders

Comment: Downvoted for two reasons. 1: This code isn't compilable nor is it correct, 2: You are using string concatenation on a path instead of the very valid and very applicable `Path.Combine`. Also, calling `ToString()` will return `System.String[]` and not a path.

Comment: @ColinM and OP: beware that `Path.Combine` will not work as intended if the 2nd argument has a leading slash as is the case here. For it to work on this string it would have to look like this: `Path.Combine(selecteddir, @"Data\storagedir.cfg")`, note how I removed the slash in front of `Data`.

Comment: Path.Combine ? Are you kidding? Good luck with Path.Combine debugging, when the others just see locals in watch

Comment: `string myPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Data", "storagedir.cfg");` Where's the complication in debugging that?